# Pandas: adding a colon to every two characters starting from middle of string in all data

Tags: pandas

My data is a pandas dataframe and looks like this:

```
ALB_1ABCD2_1  ABCD3_1  AB_1  AB_2
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062 
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
ALB*000051  ABCB4*000050  ADH4*000131  ALB*000062
```

Starting from the *, I would like to add colons between every two characters (numbers). So I want each data to look like ALB*00:00:51 or ABCB4*00:00:50.

What is the most pythonic and concise way to do this?

Edit: This is the code I used to try to get my desired output.

```
for column in df_new3.columns[2:]:
df_new3[column] = df_new3[column].str.replace("+","*")
for data_str in df_new3[column]:
    start_loc = data_str.find('*') + 1
    former_half = data_str[:start_loc]
    latter_half = ":".join(data_str[i:i+2] for i in range(start_loc, len(data_str), 2))
    full = former_half + latter_half
    data_str = full
    print(full)
```

I cannot seem to get the line "data_str = full" to work -- print(full) seems to return the data in the format I want, but I would like the values in the dataframe to be replaced by the newly formatted values.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Define your own function and convert the time here to time format , I am not using apply , since you have some corrupt data like 000062

```
def yourfunc(x):
    x=x.str.split('*',expand=True)
    x[1]=pd.to_datetime(x[1],format='%H%M%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return x.apply('*'.join,1)

for x in df:
df[x]=yourfunc(df[x])


df
Out[308]: 
   ALB_1ABCD2_1         ABCD3_1           AB_1        AB_2
0  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
1  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
2  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
3  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
4  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
5  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
6  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
7  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
8  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*000062
```

Comment: "_corrupt data_": what makes you think this is time?

Comment: @DYZ it's not time haha

Comment: @anonymous_instrument_ That's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to replace each pair of digits after an asterisk (except for the last one) with the same pair of digits and a colon:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r"\\*(\d{2}(?!$))", r"\1:")

#   ALB_1ABCD2_1         ABCD3_1           AB_1          AB_2
#0  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*00:00:62
#1  ALB*00:00:51  ABCB4*00:00:50  ADH4*00:01:31  ALB*00:00:62
```

The `"(?!$)"` is called *negative lookahead* and means "Except for the last one."